# Здравствуйте, я новичок в программирование, вот не пойму как работает этот срез. s[x:x + n]

Tags: python

Мне не понятно как здесь работает 'n', что она прибавляет.

```
s = 'a b c d e f'.split()
n = 3
my_list = list()
for x in range(0, len(s), n):
    my_list.append(s[x:x + n])
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Как и любой другой срез. Что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: x получается равен 0 и 3...  в первом случае срез от 0 до 3  `[0:0+3]`, во втором аналогично [3:3+3] то есть от 3 до 6. P.S. Не бойтесь вставлять print() в любые непонятные участки кода чтобы понять что там находится в данный момент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте абстрагируемся от конкретно вашего кода для начала.

Допустим, у нас есть список `s = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
И мы возьмём срез `slice = s[2:5]`. В переменную `slice` внесётся такой список: `[2, 3, 4]`.

То есть, в общем смысле будет так:

срез `s[a:b]` даст нам список от `a` до `b - 1` (включая оба как `a`, так и `b - 1`)

P.S. не забываем, что в программировании счёт везде идёт с `0`

---

В вашем же случае мы видим фиксированную переменную `n = 3` и цикл `for`, перебирающий все значения от `0` до `len(s) - 1` (включительно) с шагом в `n = 3`.

Имеем, что у вас будет 2 вызова цикла:

1. x = 0: `s[x:x + n]` даст `s[0:3]` то есть `['a', 'b', 'c']`
2. x = 3: `s[x:x + n]` даст `s[3:6]` то есть `['d', 'e', 'f']`

---

Немного практики поможет вам разобраться лучше.

---

Всем добра-бобра

Comment: Спасибо разобрался.